# Check state of multiple UISwitches

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, uiswitch

At a certain point in my app, the user is presented with tons of UISwitches. When this view leaves, I want to check the position of each switch, and if it is on, to save a simple string into core data for that switch just letting me know it is on. The problem is, I don't want to manually make a bunch of if statements like the following:

```
if(switch1 is on){
    save attribute in core data switch1checked as @"YES i am checked"
}
```

what would be the best practice for checking different UISwitches with different outlet names? I was thinking something like below:

```
for (UIView *view in [self.scrollView subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UISwitch class]]) {
        UISwitch *switchView = (UISwitch *)view;
        if(switchView.isOn == YES){
            [self saveToCoreData];
        }

    }
}
```

The problem isn't saving to Core Data, the problem is how to know which switch it is on. Any ideas? I'm sure it's simple, but I can't think of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `tag` to each switch. Don't wait for the view to be closed, add a `target` and `action` to each of your switches and handle the value change. When the value changes, use the `tag` to determine which switch changed and save that data immediately.

The `tag` could be an index into an array of switch identifiers...

Comment: Can you set the tag programmatically? e.g. the same code above but using a counter loop like: for(each switch){           double i = 0;
            switchView.tag = i;
            i++;}

Comment: Yes, you could set the tags programatically.